# How do I get Slack to post a response to a dialog? (php)

Tags: php, slack-api

I have a slash command that creates a dialog. This works fine and returns OK when the submit button is pressed.

**OpenSlash.php**

```
// Build Dialog
$dialog =
[
    'callback_id'   => 'submit_session',
    'type'          => 'modal',
    'title'         => 'Controller Feedback',
    'submit_label'  => 'Submit',
    'elements'      =>
    [
        [
            'type'  => 'textarea',
            'label' => 'Feedback',
            'name'  => 'f_feedback'
        ]
    ]
];

// define POST query parameters
$query = [
    'token' => 'xxxx',
    'dialog' => json_encode($dialog),
    'trigger_id' => $triggerid
];

// define the curl request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://slack.com/api/dialog.open');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// set the POST query parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($query));

// execute curl request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close
curl_close($ch);
```

When I try to output or log the payload post, I am not getting anything returned. Am I missing something?

**Response.php**

```
$payload = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'payload');
$decoded = json_decode($payload);
file_put_contents("post.log", $_POST['payload']);
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having this problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

```
$payload_json   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'payload', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
$payload        = json_decode ($payload_json, true);

$type           = $payload['type'];
$callback       = $payload['callback_id'];

if ($type == 'dialog_submission' && $callback == 'submit_session')
{
    $f_var1   = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$payload['submission']['f_var1']);
    $f_var2   = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$payload['submission']['f_var2']);
    ... do other stuff... 
}
```